# Pass linq query result to viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, viewmodel

In my MVC web application, I have linq query that feth the record from database, I want to display that record on view using viewmodel. I have tried with following code.

```
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult CreatePDF()
    {
        RentalAgreementEntities db = new RentalAgreementEntities();
        String strSession1 = "39726-10275-6027589725",strStatus = "Y",strUserType = "L";

        var q = (from um in db.User_Master
                 join ut in db.UserType_Master on um.US_SerialNo.ToString() equals ut.UT_UserNo
                 join pu in db.PropertyUser_Master on ut.UT_SerialNo.ToString() equals pu.PU_UserNo
                 join pr in db.Property_Master on pu.PU_PropertyNo equals pr.PR_SerialNo.ToString()
                 where pr.PR_MakerID == strSession1
                 && ut.UT_Status == strStatus
                 && ut.UT_UserType == strUserType

                 select new 
                 {
                     um.US_FirstName,
                     um.US_LastName
                 }
                 ).AsEnumerable().Select(um => new User_Master {

                US_FirstName = um.US_FirstName.ToString(),
                US_LastName=um.US_LastName

            }).ToList();

        var myviewmodel=new viewmodelPDF()
        {
            lsusermaster=q.ToList();
        }
        return View("pdfgenerationvw",myviewmodel);
    }
```

I also created viemodel to manage all model's for to display on a view (Here, Just one model access code).

```
public class viewmodelPDF
{ 
  public List<User_Master> lsusermaster { get; set; }
}
```

My model class, for which I am going to fetch record from database.

```
 public partial class User_Master
{
  public string US_FirstName { get; set; }
  public string US_LastName { get; set; }
  public int US_SerialNo { get; set; }
}
//Other Models
```

Now my problem is that, In my action code , when I am trying to assign query result to the `lsusermaster` of viewmodel then it gives compiler error as belows.
[image]

I don't know, why this compile error is thrown, How can I assign query result to viemodel property?

Comment: You can, just remove the ; sign. Since you are using object notation, you can not use semicolon on each line, but a regular comma will work. Or as in this case, no sign at all.

Comment: When I remove `;` then comiler gives error `; Expected`

Comment: move the ; after the last }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var myviewmodel=new viewmodelPDF()
{
  lsusermaster=q.ToList()
};
```

Comment: Thanks, It works. in action code `lsusermaster` shows one record , but in viewmodel `lsusermaster`, It shows zero records. Is there any need to create object of `User_Master` model in viemodel class to access records?

Comment: Your code looks correct to me. When you say that it shows zero records in your viewmodel lsusermaster, what do you mean? Do you use the viewmodel lsusermaster in a view?

Comment: Yes. I am going to display record from `lsusermaster` on view.

Comment: Got it, Little problem was there on view page, I solved it, Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using an object initializer in C#, you can't use `;` between the properties, you use it at the end of the initializer

So just remove the `;` (or use a `,`, as suggested), and move it to the end of the initializer block

```
var myviewmodel=new viewmodelPDF()
{
  lsusermaster=q.ToList()
};
```

Using a `,` works even if there are no more properties... it "looks" bad, but it makes easier to add new properties should you ever need them... if the code is final, I'd not use it, but that's personal preference